# ovl unspecified number of clocks

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

is there a way to use ovl (for example an ovl_change) to check that a signal changes an unspecified number of clocks after an event? The spec lists a num_clks that must be specified, I am wondering if there is a way to make this num_clks field infinite (or if there is another way of using ovl where you don't need to specify the num_clks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `num_clks` to `$`.

I'm assuming that OVL is making a template over SVA and therefor `$` would represent an unlimited range for an assertion. If it is not in an assertion format, hopefully it is still following IEEE Std 1800 and supports and uses `$isunbounded`. See section 22.4 in IEEE Std 1800-2005 or section 20.6.3 in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) for more about `$isunbounded`.

Note, you may be limited by the OVL version's capabilities. You may need to find and visually inspect the OVL source code to know for sure.